Active profile setting not working in spring boot
I wanted the active profile be dev, and put below line in application.properties file:
spring.profiles.active=dev

However, I get following console output saying that the active profile is prod:
2024-06-13T10:02:45.540+09:00  INFO 62532 --- [profile_dbms] [  restartedMain] s.bum.profile.ProfileDbmsApplication     : The following 1 profile is active: "prod"

How the above application.properties line becomes useless?
Used tech' stack:

IDE: Spring Tool Suite 4 (version 4.23.0.RELEASE)
Lang: Java SE 17

All of my source code and github repository is shown below --
RestController:
public class HomeController {

  @Value("${application.dbms}")
  String dbmsInUse;
  
  @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
  String profiles;

  @GetMapping("/dbms")
  public void getDbms() {
    log.info("Profile: {}, DBMS: {}", profiles, dbmsInUse);
  }
}

application.properties:
spring.application.name=profile_dbms
spring.profiles.active=dev

application-dev.properties:
application.dbms=h2

application-prod.properties:
application.dbms=MariaDB

Run Confugurations

Spring Boot Profile: (none)
Arguments VM arguments: (none)


Console output:
2024-06-13T10:02:45.540+09:00  INFO 62532 --- [profile_dbms] [  restartedMain] s.bum.profile.ProfileDbmsApplication     : The following 1 profile is active: "prod"

Browser request end point:
http://localhost:8080/dbms

Console output(appended):
2024-06-13T10:11:18.903+09:00  INFO 62532 --- [profile_dbms] [nio-8080-exec-1] space.bum.profile.HomeController         : Profile: prod, DBMS: MariaDB  

Project github repository:
https://github.com/osparking/profile_dbms.git

Your code looks correct and it's working fine for me.. Are you using any command to run your application?

No, not at all. Using either one of two "run configurations", dev becomes active. However, application.properties "active" setting has no effect which is abnormal.

interesting, can you try this command java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev profile_dbms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

With that command it works, that is, console prints - The following 1 profile is active: "dev" ... Profile: dev, DBMS: h2.
